# Sorting by value pulled from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to isolate a sort by a number found at the end of a cell's value (i.e "APG-1710-082521-A4" and returning the value "4")

This is the formula that I am using:
`=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("$",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"A","$",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"A","")))))`

This formula works for getting the number isolated in a new column, but when I sort that column, it only sorts by the first digit
Example:
1,
1,
1,
1,
12,
14,
15,
15,
15,
17,
2,
2,
2,
225,

What can I do to make sure that the whole number/cell value is being read?

Comment: Add a `--` before `RIGHT` to coerce it to a number from text.

Answer (score 1):

The key to make your own formula work is given by @BigBen, but your formula is rather lenghty. Here is a formula that will extract the number from the right of your string:

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT(A1,ROW($1:$99)))
```

[image]

If you must make this dynamic (length-wise) you can both try (depending on your version of Excel):

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT(A1,ROW($A1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)))))
```

Or:

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))))
```